# Suppose $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is differentiable such that $|f'(x)|\ne1$ for all $x\in[0, 1]$. Prove $\exists !a,b\in[0,1]:f(a)=a,f(b)=1-b$

Tags: analysis, contest-math

> Suppose $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is differentiable such that
>   $|f'(x)|\ne1$ for all $x\in[0, 1]$.
>
> Prove there exist unique $a,b\in[0,1]$ such that $f(a)=a$ and
>   $f(b)=1-b$.

Not sure how I'm supposed to use the $|f'(x)|\ne1$  condition.

The $a,b$ condition geometrically means that the function intersects $x=y$ and $x=1-y$ lines.

 This is trivial if $f$ is a constant, but not sure how to proceed otherwise.

[Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) gives that there exists $c$ such that $f'(c)=f(1)-f(0)$. Useful?

Comment: Hints: You need to show existence and uniqueness. Existence: f is continuous. Uniqueness: $|f'(x)|\neq 1$ implies $|f'(x)|<1$ here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any continuous function from $[0,1]$ into itself has a fixed point. Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. If $g(a)=g(a')=0$ with $a\neq a'$ then $g'(x)=0$ for some $x$ which contradicts the hypothesis. Hence there is a unique $a$ with $g(a)=0$ or $f(a)=a$. Existence and uniqueness of $b$ follow by considering $1-f$.

Comment: Contradict which hypothesis?

Comment: $g'(x)=0$ means $f'(x)=1$.

Comment: Right. $\quad\quad$

Comment: Thanks for the [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property#The_closed_interval) argument.